# Function that sorts a vector of pairs with templated allocator and pairs

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

This is the function I have, it sorts a vector of pairs by the first element of the pair.

```cpp
std::vector<std::pair<int,std::string>>
sort_pairs(std::vector<std::pair<int,std::string>>&& items)
{
    std::sort(std::begin(items),std::end(items));
    return items;
}
```

But when I try to generalize it to accept any type of allocator and any type for the pair i get a bunch of errors (too many to paste them here). I'm using rvalue reference as argument because the function is called inside other functions, with copy argument also works but I think it would be less efficient. Here is some approach I've tryed.

```cpp
template <typename Allocator,
          typename P1 = typename Allocator::value_type::first_type,
          typename P2 = typename Allocator::value_type::second_type>
Allocator<std::pair<P1,P2>> sort_pairs(Allocator<std::pair<P1,P2>>&& items)
{
    std::sort(std::begin(items),std::end(items));
    return items;
}
```

I'd appreciate if you add some c++20 hints to the code. Like requirements.

Comment: TBH seems like `std::sort` with extra steps. Can you explain your motivation? If it's a convenience function, can you just `T&& items`?

Comment: The motivation was just improve my coding skills (functional programming), it's possible achieve the same result just using std::sort but with more args?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the fact that the underlying type is a pair salient? The body of the algorithm doesn't make use of that in any way. We can start with just:

```
template <typename R>
std::decay_t<R> sort(R&& items)
{
    std::sort(std::begin(items),std::end(items));
    return items;
}
```

Which in C++20 we can properly constrain by requiring that `R` is a range whose iterators are sortable - yeah, there's a concept for that:

```
template <std::ranges::range R>
    requires std::sortable<std::ranges::iterator_t<R>>
std::decay_t<R> sort(R&& items)
{
    std::sort(std::ranges::begin(items), std::ranges::end(items));
    return items;
}
```

If you really want to require that this is a range of pairs, you can add that as a separate constraint:

```
template <std::ranges::range R>
    requires std::sortable<std::ranges::iterator_t<R>> &&
             is_specialization_of<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>, std::pair>
std::decay_t<R> sort(R&& items)
{
    std::sort(std::ranges::begin(items), std::ranges::end(items));
    return items;
}
```

I'll leave the implementation of `is_specialization_of` as an exercise.

Comment: @ElGusanito First of all, it's not helpful to just say it doesn't work. What doesn't work, specifically? Secondly, [it does work](https://godbolt.org/z/M8q-rd) (once I fix the namespace on `iterator_t` - but then that wasn't a deduction failure so I'm not sure what you're referring to).

Comment: The problem was the compiler that showed me the same error (fails deducting template) with all the solutions even with c++20 enabled (cl.exe), in gcc works fine thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 1):

What you should use, to express your `Allocator`, is a "[template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter)".

As follows

```
template <template <typename...> class Allocator,
          typename P1, typename P2>
Allocator<std::pair<P1, P2>>
   sort_pairs (Allocator<std::pair<P1, P2>> && items)
 {
   std::sort(std::begin(items),std::end(items));
   return items;
 }
```

Starting from C++17 you can use `typename` instead of `class` defining it

```
// ..............................VVVVVVVV                                     
template <template <typename...> typename Allocator,
```

but `class` is still valid and, IMHO, preferable.

Observe that `Allocator` intercept `std::vector` (the template class, not a specific specialization as `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>`) so you can't extract `P1` and `P2` from it as in your example

```
// ....................VVVVVVVVV  not usable this way                       
typename P1 = typename Allocator::value_type::first_type
```

you should write

```
typename Allocator<std::pair<P1, P2>>::value_type::first_type
```

but, obviously, you can't use it to give a default type to `P1` because you have to know `P1`.

Fortunately, `P1` and `P2` can be deduced from the `items` argument, so you don't need default types.

Comment: Sorry but the example that you provided doesn't work, Here is the godbolt link, please tell me if I've implemented your function badly. [Godbolt Link](https://godbolt.org/z/VM7E4L)

Comment: @ElGusanito - My example works; It's the way you call my example that doesn't works. The function (as in your question) wait (`&&`) for a r-value reference. So you can't call it (`my_sort(v);`) with a l-value reference. You have to accept a l-value reference in the function (`&` instead of `&&`) or you have to pass a r-value reference (`my_sort(std::move(v));`). But if you use `std::move()` over `v`, you can't use it after it (undefined behavior, if I remember correctly) so you have to copy the returned value to a new vector, so `auto v2 = my_sort(std::move(v));` and loop over `v2`, not `v`.

Comment: Sorry and thanks, I've learned a lot about templates thanks to your awnser.

Comment: @ElGusanito - You're welcome. The important thing is that you've learned.